# How to spell "woah"

Tags: orthography

How do I spell the word *woah* as used in surprise or excitement? Is it similar to *wow* except for the last *w*?

Comment: I knew it as Whoa!

Comment: Olright thanks. That what wiki said too, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whoa

Comment: Rather than surprise/ excitement, it's more like 'now, not so fast' or 'hold it'', I think.

Comment: But http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whoa has many meanings for it.

Comment: As an expression of delight or surprise (1980s) it has gradually superseded *wow*, which was very popular in the 1960s. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whoa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **whoa**
>   *exclam*.
>   used as a command to a horse to make it stop or slow down.
>   • *informal* used as a greeting, to express surprise or interest, or to command attention: *whoa, that's huge!*
>   <sub>NOAD</sub>

It's still *whoa* in all but Internet-speak.